# stemDocument R text mining

Tags: r, tm, stemming

My data is a txt file and looks as follows:
words number_doc
overwiew 1
client 1
store 1
marge 1
price 2
stock 2
economics 2

The numbers of the documents are sorted (from the smallest to the largest). Now I want for each document all the words that belongs to the document. Now they stand in a column, but I want al the words in a textDocument (from the package tm, because it is neccesary for some functions in that package). I did this as follows:

```
 data <- read.table("poging.txt", header = TRUE)
 data

 doc <- c()
 #I paste all the words from a document together:
 doc[1] <- paste(data[1:4,1], collapse = ' ')
 doc[2] <- paste(data[1:4,1], collapse = ' ')

 #Make a data.frame of it
 doc_df <- data.frame(docs = doc, row.names = 1:2)

 #Install package
 install.packages("tm")
 library(tm)

 #Make a Dataframesource of it so that each row is seen as a document
 ds <- DataframeSource(doc_df)
 inspect(VCorpus(ds))

 #Now I want to stem for example document number 1
 stemDocument(ds[[1]])
```

But by using `ds[[1]]` as argument, it doesn't work. He can't find document number 1.
Can someone help me?

In the examples om the package `tm` they use the data `crude`. I want that my data is the same format as that from `crude`.

Silke

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. If we can copy/paste the code into R to re-create the problem, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I've made a more simple case with only 2 documents now, but the problem is still the same. Hope you can help me!

Comment: But we still can't run the code because it requires "poging.txt". In order to be helpful, it must be a contained, minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've made a txt file of the data on the top of my question. You can copy paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stemDocument()` is meant to be use with a TextDocument, not a DataSource. You want to use the DataSource to create a corpus, then you can extract the documents from there.

```
ds <- DataframeSource(doc_df)
corpus <- VCorpus(ds)
stemDocument(corpus[[1]])
```

Note that `stemDocument` will return a new document and will not update the corpus permanently. So if you wish to do anything with the output, be sure to save it somewhere.